# Crear Stored Procedure para actualizar una tabla desde archivos csv en red de la PC

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

Soy iniciado en la herramienta. Estoy buscando la manera de crear un SP que actualice una tabla ya creada en una base de datos, esta se llama **dbo.HogarTOTAL**

Busco que dicha tabla esté conformada por un conjunto de tablas, que cada una sigue una linea trimestral en el tiempo (es decir, *Hogar21T3* se llama la tabla correspondiente al tercer trimestre del año 2021, *Hogar21T4* es la correspondiente al cuarto trimestre de 2021, y asi sucesivamente).

En síntesis, mi duda principal es no saber cómo crear un procedimiento en Transact-SQL que actualice dbo.HogarTOTAL agregandole las tablas de cada trimestre que se van agregando en determinada carpeta en una red de trabajo. La idea es que dbo.HogarTOTAL vaya teniendo mediante UNION todas las tablas almacenadas.

Espero que se logre entender cual es la duda y mas que nada busco escuchar recomendaciones de qué hacer al respecto.

Comment: Suena a que tenes un problema en el diseño de la DB.. porque tenes una tabla por trimestre?

Comment: Lamentablemente se va creando un informe trimestral y entonces se crea una tabla respectiva para ese periodo de tiempo. ¿Crees que habría alguna manera de poder realizar igual lo que consulté?

Comment: Supongo que podes recorrer la tabla que tiene la definicion de las tablas y crear un query dinamico para luego ejecutarlo.. pero algun experto seguro tiene una idea mejor de como se podria hacer...

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias. Seguiré esperando a ver que se puede hacer.

Comment: Suena a que debes investigar mas para resolver el trabajo por el que te pagan